# Time format issue in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, datetime-format

I am changing the date timeZone by the bellow code. It returns nil when I set the device time format to 12 Hours in settings and working fine when the time format is 24 hrs.

Any help?

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-05-09T14:54:16.0971803Z")

    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
    if let date_ = date {
        let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date_)
        return dateFormatter.date(from: strDate)
    }
```

Comment: what you want as output  ?

Comment: @Lion
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-05-09T14:54:16.0971803Z")
This assign nil when I set 12 hours format in device settings